# Creating a Jar file as a one-liner with multiple classes in CMD/Powershell

Tags: java, powershell, jar, cmd

I am trying to convert the following Linux JAR command to run as a one-liner in CMD:

```
$ jar cvf JarName.jar */*.class
```

I am finding it hard to do as there is no file expansion in CMD / Powershell like there is in *nix based shells.  I know I can do this by creating a manifest with the appropriate class files, but the one liner just seems so nice and simple.  I have tried playing with DIR and pipes but it appears the class files are arguments and don't come from STDIN.  I have also tried playing with the FOR command but I can't figure out how to make it a single line.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks very much!
Ms. Plants

Comment: Does that `*/*.class` just get all the .class files in child directories of where the file is being run?

Comment: `*/*.class` gets all class files that are stored in a subdirectory of the current directory.  Thanks!

Comment: maybe in PowerShell ... `gci -recurce -filter *.class | % {jar cvf JarName.jar $_.FullName}`

Comment: Hi Chris N.  Thanks for your comment.  It looks like your command is very close but creates a jar for every single `.class` rather than packaging all class files together.  I might play with it more later as this seems like it has potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder tree contains only the files you want to include in the .jar file you can do this:

```
jar cvf JarName.jar .
```

Otherwise the simplest way might be to duplicate the folder structure with just the class files via `robocopy` and then `jar` the duplicate:

```
robocopy "C:\path\to\classdir" "C:\path\to\classdir_dup" *.class /s
jar cvf JarName.jar -C "C:\path\to\classdir_dup" .
rd /s /q "C:\path\to\classdir_dup"
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar!  The only thing that I had to add was the `/S` option to the robocopy command and this worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but are you just trying to add all the class files in all subdirectories? I think it works like this:

```
jar cvf JarName.jar *.class
```

Comment: That won't recurse into subfolders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, nograpes, but Ansgar is right -- it doesn't recurse into the subdirectories.  I have more than one subdirectory each of which has class files that should be included in the jar...